# Problem with VBA print to pdf error code in windows 10 environment

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which works fine in windows 7 and other windows version environments, but when some of the users have been upgraded to Windows 10 (myself included)

This is a macro enabled sheet which has worked fine for 3 years, and as far as I can tell the only change is the 'upgrade' to windows 10!

this is the bit of code which seems to fail:

```
'saveas function for pdf
ws.range("A1:K69").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDf, _
filename:=path & fname, _
Quality:-xlqualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True' _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

I get a Run-Time error Method 'ExportAsFixedFormat' of Object 'Range' failed.  But when someone in an earlier windows environment runs the code it works perfectly and I get the pdf created, saved and opened for the user to insert other documents into.

Driving me mental, and I cannot work out why this would fail - and also sporadically as well.

Comment: Please provide a full [mcve]. What is `ws`? How is it defined? `Quality:-clqualityStandard` should be `Quality:=clqualityStandard`. Fix your typos. Make sure the code you show here is **exactly** the code you use (the code you actually show should throw compile errors and not run at all).

Comment: I believe, all of Microsoft products recently got an upgrade. So I think x1TypePDF might be different now

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment. And reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat) helps "Type can be either `xlTypePDF` or `xlTypeXPS`" and it never was `x1TypePDF`. Note the difference between `xl` (lower case `L`) and `x1` (one). The correct syntax is the lower case `L`. Also see [xlFixedFormatType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfixedformattype).

Comment: Also there is a extremely low probability that Microsoft will make such a method incompatible. (Microsoft still carrys 20 years old bugs around just because of compatibility reasons).

Comment: PEH - that was a typo in my comment above, the code is xl and not x1

Answer (score 0):

I use the below to auto save an excel sheet as PDF, should try and save it to the excel file location and name it after the tab name.

If you set a print area on the sheet for the range you want to view in the PDF first, it should work :)

Hope it helps

```
Sub Export_Summary()

'
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strTime As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet
strTime = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm")

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

'replace spaces and periods in sheet name
strName = Replace(wsA.Name, " ", "")
strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")

'create default name for savng file
strFile = strName & "_" & strTime & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

'user can enter name and
' select folder for file
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

'export to PDF if a folder was selected
If myFile <> "False" Then
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```